# Why will my JAR file not run after obfuscating it with ProGuard? Main class is getting obfuscated / library

Tags: java

I've looked at many different tuts. on Youtube and scoured the forums but I've had to result to asking a question.

Everytime I obfuscate my jar file (with Jnative hook library) the main class gets obfuscated too EVEN WHEN I PUT IN THE CONFIG;

```
-keep public class com.apk.Main { 
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]); 
}
```

Why is it doing this? I need to obfuscate my work and it simply won't let me...

CONFIG

```
    -injars Native.jar
-outjars Out

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\rt.jar'

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize


-keep,allowshrinking class com.apk.Main

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Also keep the main class
-keep public class com.apk.Main

# and if that doesnt work dont touch the publicstaticvoidmainstringargs

-keep public class com.apk.Main { 
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]); 
}
```

}

EDIT

So I'm fairly confident that it's because my main class is getting obfuscated, but I have no idea why - since I've created a config which shouldn't do that.

Comment: That should prevent main method from being obfuscated. Is it obfuscating the main method?

Comment: @RamandeepNanda yeah it is still... Its really weird since I assumed that would stop it.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this in proguard rules file?

Comment: @RamandeepNanda I posted the config.